# Android 6(M) permission issue (create directory not working)

Tags: android, android-camera, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have this code for creating directory for saving pictures:

```
        File storageDir = null;
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {                
            storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "myphoto");
            if (!storageDir.mkdirs()) {                    
                if (!storageDir.exists()){                       
                    Log.d("photo", "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        return storageDir;
```

**storeDir** returns `"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/myphoto/"` below android 6 and on android 6 it returns `null`.

I have permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

`buildToolVersion 23
 targetSdkVersion 23`

How to fix?

Comment: "storeDir returns "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/myphoto/" below android 6 and on android 6 it returns "file:///"" -- that code is returning `File` objects, not strings. Beyond that, what is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: it returns null actually

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As @CommonsWare answered, there is run-time permission asking concept on Android M, so in new approach, permissions are not asked when installing the app but when trying to use specific feature of phone which requests permission, at run-time. User later can disable permission from `phone settings->app->yourapp->permissions` as well. So you have to check before doing something with that permission, and ask user:

```
int REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE=1;
////...
        File storageDir = null;
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
            //RUNTIME PERMISSION Android M
            if(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED==ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "myPhoto");
            }else{
                requestPermission(context);
            }    

        } 
        return storageDir;
////...
        private static void requestPermission(final Context context){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity)context,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
            // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
            // For example if the user has previously denied the permission.

            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.permission_storage))
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.tamam, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
            }).show();

        }else {
            // permission has not been granted yet. Request it directly.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }

///...

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case UtilityPhotoController.REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
                if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            getResources().getString(R.string.permission_storage_success),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            getResources().getString(R.string.permission_storage_failure),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tested in emulator , if u give runtime permission , need to kill the process and restart again?

Comment: @ParaSara no you don't need

Comment: I  faced as same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947638/requesting-and-allowing-write-external-storage-permission-at-runtime-has-no-effe

Comment: @ParaSara maybe it is device specific bug, if user grants write_permission, it should immediately take effect, i never seen restart

Comment: ok :) , so you tested in real device, right ? i have tested in the emulator. In Emulator I have to kill the process and restart process to runtime permission work

Comment: @ParaSara yes on real devices

Comment: may be problem in emulator

Comment: I was getting stuck over here and here finally i found the solution after doing lot's of googling, Thank you very much @JemshitIskenderov
Your answer `phone settings->app->yourapp->permissions` did help me

Answer (score 15):

You are running this on an Android 6.0+ environment and you have a `targetSdkVersion` of 23.

In that case, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is part of [the Android 6.0 runtime permission system](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html). Either revise your app to participate in this system, or drop your `targetSdkVersion` below 23.

Comment: i have tested it without permission, no luck

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov: I did not tell you to remove the permission. I told you to revise your app to participate in the Android 6.0 runtime permission system, or to drop your `targetSdkVersion` below 23.

Comment: what do you mean by "revise your app to participate in the Android 6.0 runtime permission system"?

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov: I mean what I wrote. There is a link in my answer to [the documentation on the Android 6.0 runtime permission system](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html). It is rather long and involved. My recommendation is that you drop your `targetSdkVersion` below 23 for the time being.

Comment: Either with permission or without permission it had to work (i have tried both) instead of asking permission at runtime  right? Bu it does not. I don't think it is because of permission.

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov: "Either with permission or without permission it had to work (i have tried both) instead of asking permission at runtime right?" -- no, it does not. Please change your `targetSdkVersion` to 22 and include the `<uses-permission>` element in your manifest.

Comment: Ok i see there is new settings for granting permissions to applications on phone settings as well on android m. Just i have to do it programatically

Comment: No CommonsWare you are wrong. I have all permissions set up properly and I still cannot mkdir. How can this possibly be? What is wrong with Android why do they do this to us as developers. The last thing anyone needs is to waste hours trying to figure why they can't make a directory. PATHETIC!

Comment: I have all the permissions needed, and verified and file.mkdir() always comes back false WTFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.  How do you write to external storage after api 23? Anyone?

Comment: @JamisonMan111: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] demonstrating what you tried and what your specific symptoms are.

Answer (score 4):

You must get permission for this work like:

[image]

for do it impliment this code:

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

        } else {


            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},23
                    );
        }
    }
```

good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

             if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            if (checkPermission()) {
                                //do your work
                            } else {
                                requestPermission();
                            }
                        }
               }


                protected boolean checkPermission() {
                    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                protected void requestPermission() {

                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Write External Storage permission allows us to do store images. Please allow this permission in App Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 100);
                        }
                    }
                }

            @Override
            public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                    case 100:
                        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            //do your work
                        } else {
                            Log.e("value", "Permission Denied, You cannot use local drive .");
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: NOPE still no go, cannot mkdir????? I have all the permissions needed and verified after almost an hour of wasted time

Comment: I am facing same problem, did you find the solution @JamisonMan111