# Directory creation not working in Marshmallow Android

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am creating directory in my native application.It is working perfectly in Android 5.0, But In Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) some times it worked and some times not.I am using following code to create new directory.I am saving Video and image file in directory.

```
 public static void createApplicationFolder() {
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), File.separator + Config.VIDEO_COMPRESSOR_APPLICATION_DIR_NAME);
    f.mkdirs();
    f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), File.separator + Config.VIDEO_COMPRESSOR_APPLICATION_DIR_NAME + Config.VIDEO_COMPRESSOR_COMPRESSED_VIDEOS_DIR);
    f.mkdirs();
    f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), File.separator + Config.VIDEO_COMPRESSOR_APPLICATION_DIR_NAME + Config.VIDEO_COMPRESSOR_TEMP_DIR);
    f.mkdirs();

}
```

Comment: in android M you need a to ask permission for that.

Comment: I already added permission in manifest and also tried run time permission.But its not working.any other way ?

Comment: yes you should ask for that

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225506/android-6m-permission-issue-create-directory-not-working

Comment: @Csharp have a look at my edited answer

Comment: @Csharp any updates?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public class MyDevIDS extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final int REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION = 123;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            if (CheckPermission(MyDevIDS.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // you have permission go ahead
                createApplicationFolder();
            } else {
                // you do not have permission go request runtime permissions
                RequestPermission(MyDevIDS.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

            switch (permsRequestCode) {

                case REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION: {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // you have permission go ahead
                        createApplicationFolder();
                    } else {
                        // you do not have permission show toast.
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        public void RequestPermission(Activity thisActivity, String Permission, int Code) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                    Permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                        Permission)) {
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                            new String[]{Permission},
                            Code);
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean CheckPermission(Context context, String Permission) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Devices running on Android M, you cant directly write data to storage. you need to ask permission for that.

[this](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html) link might be helpful

So the permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` should be asked at run time here.

```
public  boolean permissions() {
//cheeck id device is Android M 

 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    if(checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //your permission is granted
        return true;
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        return false;
    }
}
else {
 //permission is automatically granted on devices lower than android M upon installation

    return true;
}
}
```

You will also need to override **onRequestPermissionsResult()** callback method. and you can add the logic here.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

    //Add your logic of saving a file to directory. 
}

}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Please add the relevant code from the referenced link. In future, this link might change hence making the answer non useful to future visitors.

Comment: Does it applies for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE also ?

Answer (score 0):

In Android Marshmallow you need to ask for [dangerous permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous), including STORAGE permission group, in runtime.
I know a nice library that can make your life easier, [RxPermissions](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions).

You can ask for a permission with few code:

```
RxPermissions.getInstance(this)
.request(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
.subscribe(granted -> {
    if (granted) { // Always true pre-M
       // I can write to the storage now
    } else {
       // Oups permission denied
    }
});
```