# No permission to access this object error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload files using firebase. The code works fine on devices with only internal storage but while trying on devices with external storage(SD card) it shows `User does not have permission to access this object. Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403` error.

My manifest file contains following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Your Android OS Version is 6.0 if yes then you have get runtime permission Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141523/directory-creation-not-working-in-marshmallow-android/38141778#38141778

Comment: Can we see some code which you are trying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default security rules for storage buckets require you to sign in with firebase **authentication**.  You can use any authentication method.  At a minimum, you must you anonymous signin by:

- enable anonymous signin in the "Auth" tab of the Firebase website
- follow the steps here to add code to sign in: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth#authenticate-with-firebase-anonymously

You can also set your rules to allow access to anyone -- including those who have not yet authenticated.  **But** this is **not** recommended as your data will not be secure.

You will just need to use `request.auth` in your rules instead of just `auth`.

See [StorageException: StorageException has occurred. User does not have permission to access this object.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/X37PwJs6I0A)

Also [Secure User Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security) to get more idea.

I hope its helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Check if target SDK version in build.gradle is 23, if so you need to implement runtime permissions or change it to 22

Answer (score 1):

Do not build your project with `targetSdk` set to anything higher than `22` if your project requires additional permissions, because you must then support [Runtime Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). As a quick solution, change `targetSdk` to `22`, clean and rebuild your project and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to your firebase console

2.Go to your app

3.Click on the authentication button in the left hand side

4.Click on the sign-in method tab

5.Hover on the anonymous item below in the list

6.Click on the pencil button at the right side of the item

7.Click on enable and then save

This should work

Answer (score 0):

just go to the authentication and allow sign in method for anonymous and your problem will completely finish