# Action Dial works but Action Call gives issue and doesn't do what I want

Tags: android

This code works like a charm but at dial screen i want it to auto make call. however i have changed ACTION_DIAL to ACTION CALL and still no luck. I have give full access in manifest but still not doing what i want it to. please help.

```
EditText firstNumber;
Button btnAdd;
int number = 35;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main23);

    Toast.makeText(Main23Activity.this,
            "Type in your Pin Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button12);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
                String text= et.getEditableText().toString();

                String character = Character.toString((char) number);

                Toast.makeText(Main23Activity.this,
                        "Adding Money to your account has never been this easy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("*221*" + text + "#")));
                startActivity(intent);

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    });

   }
}
```

MANIFEST FILE

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
</uses-permission>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="Splashscreen"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>


    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main22Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main23Activity" >
    </activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
 App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: whats issue you are facing it will be in your logcat post it here.

Comment: Call requires permission which may be rejected by user. Code to explicitly check to see if the permission is available

Comment: it runs perfect just doesn't do what i want

Comment: can you please post your manifest

Comment: check the edited post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dial like this below and don't forget to add the relevant permission to your manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

```
    Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:123456789");
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
    startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: but wont that defeat the purpose of auto calling ?

Comment: im trying now one moment

Comment: did same thing actually

Comment: your android OS version is 6.0?

Comment: let me double check

Comment: phone is 6.0.1 and i set to 5.0.1 and higher on android studio for emulator

Comment: have you get runtime permission of from user?

Comment: that i havent because im not sure how.

Comment: the phone doesn't prompt at the corrent menu

Comment: hmmm thats the problem your android 6.0 you have to get runtime permission from user otherwise by only declaring them manifest is not enough. Look here in my earlier answer and then try and comment if still have issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141523/directory-creation-not-working-in-marshmallow-android/38141778#38141778

Comment: would it be the same way if i did it for a earlier version ? because now that i think about it i want the app to work for anyone and version 4.0 or higher. also implementing what you have to work with my code will be a challenge.

Comment: Yes runtime permission support backwards too.

Comment: Ok I'll check your page out again. Thank you

Comment: @ShevanMurat you are welocme.

Comment: you don't need any permissions for ACTION_DIAL

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin code:**

```
fun makeCall(){
       val phoneNumber = "12345678"
       val dialIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
       dialIntent.data = 
       Uri.parse("tel:$phoneNumber")
       startActivity(dialIntent)
    }
```

**Then call the function:**

```
binding.buttonCall.setOnClickListener{
  makeCall() }
```

**Add permission in the AndroidManifest.xml**
[image: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"]