# onclick of listview in android marshmallow version

Tags: java, android, listview, android-6.0-marshmallow

I added `listview` in my app...If i click `listview` in marshmallow version mobile..my app is hanging...I am getting below error...On click code...but other versions its working good..I don''t know whats the problem in my app..can anyone help me

```
           public class ConfigureFragment extends Fragment {
                  }

      public class DeviceListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
        ArrayList<String> accessPoints;
        ArrayList<String> groupTitle;
        ArrayList<String> securityType;

        public DeviceListAdapter() {
            accessPoints = new ArrayList<String>();
            groupTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
            groupTitle.add("apps");
        }

        public void setAccessPoints(ArrayList<String> aPs, ArrayList<String> sType) {
            accessPoints = new ArrayList<String>(aPs);
            securityType = new ArrayList<String>(sType);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return accessPoints.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public View getChildView(int gi, int ci, boolean isLastChild, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);
            final TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.apName);
            textView.setText(accessPoints.get(ci));
            textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
                    window.setAttributes(wlp);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.confirm_dialog_layout);
                    Button yes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
                    Button no = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.noButton);

                    TextView message = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.confirmMessage);

                    yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            String ssid = (String) textView.getText();
                            WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
                            conf.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";
                            List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
                            for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
                                if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + ssid + "\"")) {
                                    wifiManager.disconnect();
                                    wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                                    wifiManager.reconnect();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                        ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) parent;
                        groupTitle.remove(0);
                        groupTitle.add(ssid);
                        expandableListView.collapseGroup(0);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

**error in logcat**

```
> E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!! E/NEW_BHD:
> Cannot run on production devices!
> I/NetworkController.MotorolaMobileSignalController(1):   
> MotorolaMobilePhoneStateListener.onSignalStrengthsChanged:  Entered:
> signalStrength=SignalStrength: 31 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647
> 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte level=4
> 
> I/InputDispatcher: Dropped event because it is stale.
> I/InputDispatcher: Dropped event because it is stale. E/NEW_BHD:
> Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!! E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run
> on production devices!
> 
> 
> I/InputDispatcher: Application is not responding: Window{6a1a2b5 u0  
> com.abcd.Main/com.abcd.main.MainActivity}.   It has been 9573.9ms
> since event, 5001.1ms since wait started.   Reason: Waiting to send
> non-key event because the touched window has not   finished processing
> certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  
> Wait queue length: 3.  Wait queue head age: 30816.1ms.
> 
> I/SFPerfTracer:      triggers: (rate: 0:199) (67991 sw vsyncs) (0
> skipped) (516:666786 vsyncs) (518:778125) W/System.err:
> java.net.SocketTimeoutException W/System.err:     at     
> libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:594) 0
> W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:552)
> W/System.err:     at 
> java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.doRecv(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:163)
> W/System.err:     at  
> java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:171)
> W/System.err:     at
> java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:274) W/System.err:
> at com.abcd.manager.Manager$tOp$5.run(Manager.java:1542) W/System.err:
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) W/System.err: Caused by:
> android.system.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
> W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
> W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:189)
> W/System.err:     at
> libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:250) W/System.err: 
> at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:549) W/System.err:  ...
> 5 more E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
> E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices! I/InputDispatcher:
> Dropped event because it is stale. I/InputDispatcher: Dropped event
> because it is stale.
```

Comment: try by using RecyclerView!

Comment: @rakesh is it working fine in kitkat?

Comment: yes bro..its working fine all version...except marshmallow...above is the error I am getting is logcat for marshmallow version..

Comment: @rakesh have you get runtime permissisons from user.

Comment: I dint get runtime permissions ..how?

Comment: @rakesh my earlior answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141523/directory-creation-not-working-in-marshmallow-android/38141778#38141778

Answer (score 0):

You have to get `runtime permission` from user in `android 6.0 and greeter` see my [**earlier answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141523/directory-creation-not-working-in-marshmallow-android/38141778#38141778) to how to get runtime permission from user.

**Note:** change your permission to `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`