# Requesting permission at run time - Android

Tags: android

I was trying to create one demo app using **Google Play** services location. It's working fine in my mobile phone but it shows the location for short period of time. However, the emulator didn't display any location. Any suggestion is appreciated..

The current version of my **Emulator - 6.0** and **targetSdkVersion 24**

Here is the MainActivity Code

```
package com.example.android.mylocation;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.jar.Manifest;
import android.Manifest.permission;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener{

    private final String LOG_TAG = "MyLocation";
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private TextView mTextView;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /** Create Google Api Client */
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Google Api Client Created");

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
    }

    /** This method will connect the Google Api Client */
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Connect the Google Play Services");
    }

    /** This method will disconnect the Google Api Client */
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Google Play Services Connected");

        try{
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Priority High Accuracy");

            mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);

            /** Request the permissions you need */
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Self Permission is not Granted");
                //Request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
        }





/*        try {
            //mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

        }
        catch(SecurityException e){
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "User permission");

        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION: {

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Check the User Response");

                //If request is cancelled, the request arrays are empty
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    try {
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Check the user location");

                        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
                        //mTextView.setText(location.toString());

                    }
                    catch(SecurityException e){
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Permission denied");
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        /*if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }*/
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Connection Suspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Location Change Detected");

        mTextView.setText(location.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Check answers there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141523/directory-creation-not-working-in-marshmallow-android/38141778#38141778

Comment: Thanks it works for Emulator..however my app is showing the location for short period of time (2-3 s) then its gone from the app.