# Android onRequestPermissionsResult in AsyncTask

Tags: android, permissions

When I want to use `onRequestPermissionsResult()` in AsyncTask, I get an error. I must use permission in Android 6.0.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){
    switch(permsRequestCode){
        case 200:
            boolean writeAccepted = grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            break;
    }
}
```

Error message is ( @Override line ) :

```
method does not override method from its superclass
```

How can I catch `onRequestPermissionsResult()` in AsycnTask ? I have activity but I can't this.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141523/directory-creation-not-working-in-marshmallow-android/38141778#38141778

Comment: Well, you can't handle `onRequestPermissionsResult()` inside an `AsyncTask`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I know that I use permission but I don't catch onRequestPermissionsResult in my AsyncTask

Answer (score 4):

> How can I catch onRequestPermissionsResult() in AsycnTask ?

You can't. You need to implement `onRequestPermissionsResult()` on the same Java class that you used for `requestPermissions()`. So:

- If you used some subclass of `Activity` for `requestPermissions()`, you need to implement `onRequestPermissionsResult()` on that same `Activity` subclass
- If you used some subclass of `Fragment` for `requestPermissions()`, you need to implement `onRequestPermissionsResult()` on that same `Fragment` subclass

You are welcome to *execute* an `AsyncTask` from within `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, if that is appropriate for your use case.