# CheckPermissions Error for LocationManager in Android Studio

Tags: android, geolocation, android-6.0-marshmallow, locationmanager, android-api-levels

I had a good working app for GetGeoLocation for API level 23( Using checkSelfPermission). But, then i had to make it compatible with API level 21. So, checkSelfPermission didn't work as it was introduced in API Level 23.

So, i changed the code to accomodate this:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CheckForCoarseLocationPermission();

}
private void CheckForCoarseLocationPermission()
{
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
    {
        // ANDROID 6.0 AND UP!
        boolean accessCoarseLocationAllowed = false;
        try
        {
            // Invoke checkSelfPermission method from Android 6 (API 23 and UP)
            java.lang.reflect.Method methodCheckPermission = Activity.class.getMethod("checkSelfPermission", java.lang.String.class);
            Object resultObj = methodCheckPermission.invoke(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
            int result = Integer.parseInt(resultObj.toString());
            if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                accessCoarseLocationAllowed = true;


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        if (accessCoarseLocationAllowed)
        {
            Log.v("TAG","Granted");
            LocationManager locationManager=    (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,new LocationListener());//ERROR Happening Here!!!!!!!!!!!
        }
        try
        {
            // We have to invoke the method "void requestPermissions (Activity activity, String[] permissions, int requestCode) "
            // from android 6
            java.lang.reflect.Method methodRequestPermission = Activity.class.getMethod("requestPermissions", java.lang.String[].class, int.class);
            methodRequestPermission.invoke(this, new String[]
                    {
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                    }, 0x12345);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the LocationManager.requestLocationUpdate is giving an error
**Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException` less**

How to tackle it, if i want to use LocationManager and CheckPermission for API level >=21.

Kindly, help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141523/directory-creation-not-working-in-marshmallow-android/38141778#38141778

Comment: if (Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSListener.this);
    }
try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { // coarse permission is granted
            // Todo
} else { // permission is not granted, request for permission
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) { // show some info to user why you want this permission
       Toast.makeText(this, "Allow Location Permission to use this functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 123 /*LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE*/);
    } else {
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 123 /*LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE*/);

    }
}
```

Note:- you must have the following permission in android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put Support library to use here like this,

```
if(android.support.v4.content.PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
...
         }
```