# android api 23 dialog alert permission does not appear

Tags: android, permissions, android-alertdialog

in my app i need the android internet permission.

I have insert the permission in the file AndroidManifest.xml (with others permissions)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

the build.gradle defaul config have the correct api level:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mytry"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

and the activity with the internet call is this:

```
public class ActivityLoginScreen extends Activity{

    final int REQUEST_INTERNET = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET)) {
                //permesso già richiesto in precedenza. Negato dall'utente
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, REQUEST_INTERNET);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_INTERNET: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "NO GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

But when i launch my app and go to the activity nothing appare.
If i go in the app settings emulator, i can see only 2 permissions.

[image]
Possible solution for this problem? Where i am in wrong?

I have use this type of request in other apps without problems

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

For all the comments type this: 
"no necessary the request because: If an app declares that it needs a normal permission, the system automatically grants the permission to the app"

this is correct.
sorry for this stupid question.
I knew the matter of default permission but my appa did not work anyway because it gave error in Internet permission.
I created a new emulator and now seems to be going.

Comment: `android.permission.INTERNET` is not considered to be a dangerous permission and thus is granted by default. No app will show the permission in the app settings. You can find a list of all permissions here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: here is sample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141523/directory-creation-not-working-in-marshmallow-android/38141778#38141778

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all permission need to be granted by user. According to [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

> System permissions are divided into two categories, normal and dangerous:
>
> - Normal permissions do not directly risk the user's privacy. If your app lists a normal permission in its manifest, the system grants the permission automatically.
> - Dangerous permissions can give the app access to the user's confidential data. If your app lists a normal permission in its manifest, the system grants the permission automatically. If you list a dangerous permission, the user has to explicitly give approval to your app.

You only need to check for permission if the permission is belong to [dangerous permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous) category (Ex: Location, Storage, Camera etc)

Answer (score 0):

Internet permission are granted by default.

It does not require user to grant it, so you already have internet permission just enable your internet.

Answer (score 0):

> Normal permissions cover areas where your app needs to access data or
>   resources outside the app's sandbox, but where there's very little
>   risk to the user's privacy or the operation of other apps. For
>   example, permission to set the time zone is a normal permission. If an
>   app declares that it needs a normal permission, the system
>   automatically grants the permission to the app. For a full listing of
>   the current normal permissions, see [Normal permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/normal-permissions.html).

As of API level 23, the following permissions are classified as **PROTECTION_NORMAL**:

For these no dailog will shown to user system will automatically grant the permission.

> ```
> ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS
> ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
> ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY
> ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
> BLUETOOTH
> BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
> BROADCAST_STICKY
> CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
> CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE
> CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
> DISABLE_KEYGUARD
> EXPAND_STATUS_BAR
> GET_PACKAGE_SIZE
> INSTALL_SHORTCUT
> INTERNET
> KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES
> MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
> NFC
> READ_SYNC_SETTINGS
> READ_SYNC_STATS
> RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
> REORDER_TASKS
> REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS
> REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES
> SET_ALARM
> SET_TIME_ZONE
> SET_WALLPAPER
> SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS
> TRANSMIT_IR
> UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT
> USE_FINGERPRINT
> VIBRATE
> WAKE_LOCK
> WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS
> ```
>
> All dangerous Android system permissions belong to permission groups.
>   If the device is running Android 6.0 (API level 23)

**PROTECTION_DANGEROUS permissions :**

These permissions will show dialog to users.[**Sample Code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141523/directory-creation-not-working-in-marshmallow-android/38141778#38141778)

> ```
> READ_CALENDAR
> WRITE_CALENDAR
> CAMERA
> READ_CONTACTS
> WRITE_CONTACTS
> GET_ACCOUNTS
> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
> ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
> RECORD_AUDIO
> READ_PHONE_STATE
> CALL_PHONE
> READ_CALL_LOG
> WRITE_CALL_LOG
> ADD_VOICEMAIL
> USE_SIP
> PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
> BODY_SENSORS
> SEND_SMS
> RECEIVE_SMS
> READ_SMS
> RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH
> RECEIVE_MMS
> READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
> WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
> ```