# Already request dangerous permission on android 6.0, and check it in setting=>app. but app still crash on android 6.0

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, unity-game-engine, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

My app crashes on android 6.0. i know it's caused by dangerous permission these is needed by ads network. I have already requested and agreed these permission, Write_external_storage, read_phone_state, needed in my app, but it still crashes. what wrong?. i use unity 5.3.5f1.

Logcat of genymotion:

> 11-25 04:22:47.034 I/art     (21550): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class
>   java.lang.Class
>
> 11-25 04:22:47.034 I/art     (21550): Rejecting re-init on
>   previously-failed  class
>   java.lang.Class
>
> 11-25 04:22:47.036 W/Ads     (21550): There was a problem getting an
>   ad response. ErrorCode: 2
>
> 11-25 04:22:47.142 W/ActivityManager(20685): Activity pause timeout
>   for ActivityRecord{bed9d6c u0
>   com.candyjuice/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t4 f}
>
> 11-25 04:22:47.210 W/EGL_emulation(21094): eglSurfaceAttrib not
>   implemented
>
> 11-25 04:22:47.210 W/OpenGLRenderer(21094): Failed to set
>   EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xdecd1d80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
>
> 11-25 04:22:47.228 W/Ads     (21550): There was a problem getting an
>   ad response. ErrorCode: 2
>
> 11-25 04:22:47.290 I/GlobalDismissManager(21481): no sender configured
>
> 11-25 04:22:47.291 D/AlertService(21481): Beginning
>   updateAlertNotification
>
> 11-25 04:22:47.294 D/AlertService(21481): No fired or scheduled alerts
>
> 11-25 04:22:47.296 D/AlertService(21481): Scheduling next alarm with
>   AlarmScheduler. sEventReminderReceived: null
>
> 11-25 04:22:47.299 D/AlarmScheduler(21481): No events found starting
>   within 1 week.
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.756 W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(21550): Google Play Store
>   is missing.
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.756 W/VungleNetwork(21550):
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
>   "api.vungle.com": No address associated with hostname
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.763 W/VungleNetwork(21550):
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
>   "api.vungle.com": No address associated with hostname
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.820 I/OneSignal(21550): GetUnsentActiveTime: 0
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.820 I/OneSignal(21550): SaveUnsentActiveTime: 2
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.851 W/AudioTrack(20685): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied
>   by client; transfer 4, track 48000 Hz, output 44100 Hz
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.867 I/Process (21550): Sending signal. PID: 21550 SIG:
>   9
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.890 E/Surface (20685): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown
>   buffer: 0xf2cb6600
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.893 D/OpenGLRenderer(20685): endAllStagingAnimators on
>   0xd9931b00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xdcc0be00
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.896 E/JavaBinder(20685): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION
>   !!!  (parcel size = 104)
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.896 W/InputMethodManagerService(20685): Got
>   RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 21550 uid
>   10060
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.896 E/JavaBinder(20685): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION
>   !!!  (parcel size = 104)
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.899 D/GraphicsStats(20685): Buffer count: 3
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.899 I/WindowState(20685): WIN DEATH: Window{d9b3a6e u0
>   com.candyjuice/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.899 W/WindowManager(20685): Force-removing child win
>   Window{3bca2c7 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{d9b3a6e u0
>   com.candyjuice/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.899 W/MediaFocusControl(20685):   AudioFocus   audio
>   focus client died
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.899 I/MediaFocusControl(20685): AudioFocus 
>   removeFocusStackEntry(): removing entry for
>   android.os.BinderProxy@dd420f4
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.902 W/WindowManager(20685): Failed looking up window
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.902 W/WindowManager(20685):
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window
>   android.os.BinderProxy@f7e5388 does not exist
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.902 W/WindowManager(20685):    at
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8733)
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.902 W/WindowManager(20685):    at
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8724)
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.902 W/WindowManager(20685):    at
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1209)
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.902 W/WindowManager(20685):    at
>   android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:558)
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.902 I/WindowState(20685): WIN DEATH: null
>
> 11-25 04:22:48.904 I/ActivityManager(20685): Process com.candyjuice
>   (pid 21550) has died

```
@Override public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
            {
                Log.i("NoodlePermissionGranter", "onRequestPermissionsResult");
                if (requestCode != PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE)
                    return;

                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    Log.i("NoodlePermissionGranter", PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                    UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(UNITY_CALLBACK_GAMEOBJECT_NAME, UNITY_CALLBACK_METHOD_NAME, PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Log.i("NoodlePermissionGranter",PERMISSION_DENIED);
                    UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(UNITY_CALLBACK_GAMEOBJECT_NAME, UNITY_CALLBACK_METHOD_NAME, PERMISSION_DENIED);
                }


                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.remove(this);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

                //SDD



                // shouldBeOkayToStartTheApplicationNow();
            }
        };
```

Comment: Add crash logs with question.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow go through this link ,how to ask a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: you need runtime permissions  look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141523/directory-creation-not-working-in-marshmallow-android/38141778#38141778

Comment: Look this too: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: I have already request these permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually request and check if the permission was granted by user to use

Check this in void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method

```
If (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_RC);
        return;
    }
```

Then Override onRequestPermissionsResult method

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_RC) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //permission granted  start reading
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No permission to read external storage.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```